# Why does my line look different than this example line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently practicing matplotlib using exercises from w3resource.com. While trying to create a graph, I noticed that my output looks different from the expected result on [the website](https://www.w3resource.com/graphics/matplotlib/basic/index.php). I'm not sure if I've made a mistake in my code or if there is another issue causing the difference.

Here are my graph and the expected graph from the w3resource exercise for comparison. The first one is mine and the second is the w3resource result.

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```py
# Library
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Variables
x1 = [10,20,30]
y1 = [20,40,10]

x2 = [10,20,30]
y2 = [40,10,30]

# Plots
plt.plot(x1,y1,'b',label='line1-dotted',linewidth=3,linestyle='dotted')
plt.plot(x2,y2,'r',label='line2-dashed',linewidth=5,linestyle='dashed')
#Settings
plt.title('Plot with two or more lines with different styles')
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.xticks([10,15,20,25,30])
plt.yticks([10,15,20,25,30,35,40])

# Show Legends
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

# Show Plots
plt.show()
```

I tried to change the linewidth and linestyle but result still the same. What is the issue between these two graphs?

Comment: Link to the w3resource example?

Comment: for the red line you want: `linestyle=':'`, but not sure about blue.

Comment: @jared here's the link https://www.w3resource.com/graphics/matplotlib/basic/index.php
the graph is from the question 7

Comment: I think they match well enough and the differences may be due to different versions, backends, or figure aspect ratios.

Comment: @OriYarden it's worked, but only the red one. but ill try to fix the blue too. thank you for helping me

Comment: @jared i think you're right. i tried to change dpi too, it's doesnt work. thank you for investing your time for my problem.

Comment: You can fine tune the line style by providing a dash tuple, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/linestyles.html) for examples.

Comment: @Stef oh wow thank you its worked. i set my linestyle to =(15, (.25, 1))